# Speed up customer login, checkout and payment

Tags: onepage-checkout, login

I have a Magento website www.moandco.com which is OK speed wise until a client chooses to login. The login process takes around a minute to complete. Once logged in browsing the catalog is extremely slow as is checking out. When paying using the secure trading payment gateway the website produces a timeout error after payment is taken as the server doesn't respond in time.

The website uses customer groups to show different products and different price to different customers. There are about 2000 products and 10 customer groups.

I have spoken to the hosting company siteground and they say the issue is not server related. They say that the issue is due to MySql not responding quick enough to complex queries and that they need to be optimised.

I have spoken to the developer who has says the coding is fine and that the issue is with the server. He has a test platform and it never times out with the customer login taking around 20 seconds even tho his hosting is not optimised for Magento in any way.

I am after some advice on what I need to do to get the website to work properly. With the host and the developer blaming each other I am caught in the middle. Any tips on how I might optimise Magento or improve performance so that logged in customers get a better user experience would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: "I have spoken to the hosting company siteground" - you have your answer - get some decent hosting! You get what you pay for - all very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly, strongly suggest you take a look at Nexcess:

1. They are a platinum certified Magento hosting partner
2. They offer extremely competitive pricing for Magento hosting which will make your jaw drop to the flaw
3. They're optimized for Magento (percona branch, redis/memcached on t2 hosting etc.)
4. They're reachable 24/7 via email & call for free & usually reply within 5 minutes

Have a look at the following

[Magento E-commerce Shared Hosting](http://www.nexcess.net/magento/hosting)

I've been using them for 3 years now and will never look elsewhere cause I'm that satisfied with their service :D

Comment: I also agree that Nexcess are a good hosting choice, but I don't think it's the 'correct' answer here - you can't solve bad coding just by throwing more processing power at it...

Comment: A slow MySQL subquery will always take a huge amount of time whatever kind of server it runs on, but you are right, we can only present what we feel are good options.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your server specifications it is hard to recommend hardware/configuration upgrades, but the good news is there are some things you can change in your configuration to impact MySQL performance.

Have a look at this link for some first steps:
http://magentospeedup.com/2013/05/31/optimize-mysql-configuration-for-magento/

Beyond that there are many resources on the web to guide you and/or your developer to increase performance in general, but chances are your best bet is to upgrade your server setup.

See if your developer or hosting provider can set up monitoring and see how much of your allocated resources are actually being used. This can help you identify your bottlenecks and tweak your hardware to compensate.

If you have a high traffic website, I highly recommend setting up dedicated hosting, preferably in a load balanced and clustered environment. This can be achieved for relatively low cost if you use virtualization. What this does is split the processes between multiple servers, each taking care of their own job. A good starter setup would be:

```
               Web Server 1
Load Balancer                Mysql Server
               Web Server 2
```

Simply put, a load balancer divides the http requests between 2 web servers, optimizing the server response times. Mysql is on its own server so it will not be hindered by the processes of the web server.

If you and/or your developer is not experienced with this, I recommend contacting your hosting provider and seeing what they recommend that is in your price range. You will see a world of difference in an optimized environment.

Comment: Except if your implementation is a mess it will negate any of the cluster benefits - they both go hand in hand - plus a triple cluster optimally only provides 300% gain. We generally use more.

Answer (score 0):

I really think others have missed the important point in the question...there is a marked difference in performance when logged in vs not logged in.  While I would like the site to perform a little better if it was mine, whether you decide to upgrade/move hosting is really up to you, but I think it's very unlikely that the hosting has anything to do with a marked performance difference when loading identical pages when logged in or not.

So, if you are seeing a marked difference in performance when logged in vs not logged in this certainly points to the possibility of there being a code based issue.  What takes the time when a server is delivering a page to the browser is building the page HTML, and this is done by executing lines of PHP code.  Each line takes a finite amount of time to execute, so you can therefore logically say that if the same page is taking longer to load when logged in vs not, the likely hood is that more lines of code are executing.  It could also be something like you are waiting for a reply from some external service before the page is delivered, but ultimately, the server is just taking more time to generate the HTML.  Also if it is down to slow DB queries, then looking for the use of subqueries is a great place to start - this can really slow things down (even for seemingly simple queries), best bet is just not to use them.

My suspicion would therefore be that the decrease in performance is being caused by something in the site codebase, making it the developers responsibility.  I don't of course know your site at all, but from information I have, it would seem a logical conclusion to draw.  My first line of investigation would be to look at third party extensions, particularly ones that are customer focused, and then start looking at other local customisations to the store.  Basically try and strip back store functionality to as close to a clean install as possible and see if the problem persists, I suspect you will find it doesn't.  Also worth noting is that comparing performance in a staging/dev environment to production is not necessarily viable as there could for instance be extensions which are only licensed on production and so are not functioning, or services which are only configured and accessible on production.  Not necessarily the case, but worth thinking about.

Comment: While I agree with most of your points, I have to say I don't think they are completely correct in this case. As the OP states: "The login process takes around a minute to complete. Once logged in browsing the catalog is extremely slow as is checking out. When paying using the secure trading payment gateway the website produces a timeout error after payment is taken as the server doesn't respond in time." This tells me the issue is most likely a server performance issue, and not the generation of HTML through PHP.

Comment: Fair enough, but for me the fact that the performance is only ever an issue once logged in, and the hosting have stated that there is slow response from MySQL (which suggests to me a third party extension or other customisation with a bad subquery or similar) is pretty conclusive. If performance was consistently poor regardless of any action I would tend to agree with you.

Comment: I believe the difference is in the customer groups altering what products to display. When not logged in Magento does not need to access the database for any customer information. I wonder if OP clears cache what is the difference in catalog browsing speed then? It is likely the pages need to be dynamically rebuilt based on customer information, and are therefor not loading cached content. If the MySQL server is on a shared VPS system I would expect it to have a slow response for the amount of requests Magento can submit.

Comment: Yep the modifications to display products according to customer group is certainly worth investigating.  A jump from  2 to 20 second page load times is very steep though - has got to point to bad development.  Be interested to find out what the actual issue is (assuming we do).